# Creating a confirmation loop

Tags: java, loops

So I'm looking to make a little text based adventure in Java. I'm a beginner and I want to have the user choose their name, gender, etc. and then for each bit, have it ask for confirmation and then once they have confirmed all of their input, ask again to make sure.

I'm not very knowledgeable about loops or that sort of thing so if someone could leave a mini-lesson and a suggestion on how to get this working, I would very much appreciate it. Thank you!

This is purely for entertainment and I welcome any constructive criticism that would make this more effective. Please do not mind the mess of pronouns.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Emu {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner menu = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What is your hero's name?");                                 
    String name = menu.nextLine();
    System.out.println("So their name is " + name + "? (Y/N)");
    char cc1 = menu.next().charAt(0);
    //If yes, continues, if not, loops back to the question where the name is set
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Okay, is " + name + " a male or female? (M/F)");
    char gender = menu.next().charAt(0);
    String genPro, genPos, genRef, genChild, genAdult;
    switch (gender) {
        case 'M':
        genPro = "He";
        genPos = "His";
        genRef = "Him";
        genChild = "boy";
        genAdult = "guy";
        break;
        case 'F':
        genPro = "She";
        genPos = "Hers";
        genRef = "Her";
        genChild = "girl";
        genAdult = "woman";
        break;
        default:
        genPro = "It";
        genPos = "It";
        genRef = "It";
        genChild = "It";
        genAdult = "It";
        break;
    }
    System.out.println("Okay! So " + name + " is a " + genChild + "? (Y/N)");
    char cc2 = menu.next().charAt(0);
    //If yes, continues, if not, loops back to the question where the gender is set

    System.out.println("So " + name + " is a " + genChild + "? (Y/N)");
    char cc3 = menu.next().charAt(0);
    //If yes, continues, if not, loops back to the question where the name is set

    System.out.println(name + " was born a healthy young " + genChild + ", in the city of PLACEHOLDER");

}
```

}

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: learn to put stuff into method, then you can loop and call these methods again and again

Answer (score 0):

A [do-while loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) is the typically used loop construct when unconditionally doing something once, and maybe having to backtrack.

Depending on how you want to handle invalid inputs (i.e. not Y or N), you may need two do-while loops. In the example below, it will keep prompting with "So their name is..." until Y or N is entered, and will only ask for the name again if N is entered.

```
char confirmation;
String name;
do
{
    System.out.println("What is your hero's name?");
    name = menu.nextLine();
    do {
        System.out.println("So their name is " + name + "? (Y/N)");
        confirmation = menu.nextLine().charAt(0);
    } while (confirmation != 'N' && confirmation != 'Y');
}
while (confirmation == 'N');
```